# Add wildcard inside CONCAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, wildcard, concatenation

I want to search on three fields: id, name, and address. I want my search to be a bit intelligent.

**subscriber table**

```
id         |     firstname     |      lastname     |     address
N29-0001   |     John          |      Doe          |     California
N29-0002   |     Jonathan      |      Morson       |     Miami
```

**my query so far**

```
select subscriberid, CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) as fullname, address, city from subscriber where id like "%N29 Joh%" or CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) like "%N29 Joh%" or address like "%N29 Joh%" or city like "%N29 Joh%"
```

I want my query to search if I typed **N29 Joh**, it will search for John Doe.

Comment: I think you should investigate full text indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a full text index.  But, if you want a match to any word and don't care about performance, you can use regular expressions:

```
select subscriberid, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname,
       address, city
from subscriber
where subscriberid regexp 'N29|Joh' or
      concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like 'N29|Joh' or
      address like 'N29|Joh' or
      city like 'N29|Joh';
```

Comment: I tried the full text index but it has an error, here's my query: SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE
MATCH(id,firstname,lastname,address)
AGAINST ('N29' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE); the error is can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list.

Comment: I should have FULLTEXT field in my table, am I right?

Comment: Yes . . . http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html.  And you need to set the minimum word length to the correct value.